# GLEW program can't find libglew.so even when file exists

Tags: glew

I am trying to set up an OpenGL development environment on a Linux machine (Mint 17). I have just installed GLEW from the source on the GLEW source forge page (Downloaded source; extracted; make install).

I want to check that everything is set up correctly and am trying to run a test program. My program compiles and links but when I try to run it I get the error "error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

libGLEW.so.1.12 exists; from what I read I think I have a 32bit executable and the SO is 64bit. However I can't find a solution to this problem; I know I need to create a 32bit library but I can't find any instructions for doing this.

Can someone please provide instructions to either (or preferably both):

1. Install 32bit libraries for GLEW
2. Link with GLEW statically

Preferably I'd like to link statically for now (I find it far more convenient for testing) but the instructions on the GLEW website only say how to do this for windows. Eventually I do plan to link everything dynamically.